# Размеры регистров и данных

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, x86-64

Предположим, в программе, написанной в 64-битном режиме, используется переменная размера dword. Предположим, надо вывести ее на экран. Как можно перекинуть ее в rdx без вреда для здоровья? Приведенный ниже код выводит 0. Исправить это у меня получается только заменив переменную на qword.

```
format PE64 console

include 'E:\Fresh\include\win64a.inc'

entry main1

section '.data' data readable writeable

        arg dd ?
        msg db '%lf',10,0

section '.text' code readable executable
main1:
        and rsp,-16

        mov [arg],1.0
        mov edx,[arg]
        mov rcx,msg
        call [printf]
        mov rcx,0
        call [ExitProcess]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с промежуточной конвертацией из float в double:

```
format PE64 console

include 'include\win64a.inc'

entry main1

section '.data' data readable writeable

        arg dd ?
        buf dq ?
        msg db '%lf',10,0

section '.text' code readable executable
main1:
        and rsp,-16

        mov [arg], 1.0

        fld [arg]
        fst [buf]

        mov rdx, [buf]
        mov rcx, msg
        call [printf]
        mov rcx,0
        call [ExitProcess]

section '.idata' import data readable

library kernel, 'kernel32.dll', \
    msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'

import kernel,\
    ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'

import msvcrt,\
    printf,'printf'
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но я пытался сэкономить лишние 4 байтика, а вы мне новую переменную предлагаете добавить. Я понимаю, что в нормальной программе всегда найдется свободная переменная, но в таком случае можно сразу все манипуляции проводить с buf.

Comment: @rancid_rot, я бы посоветовал не экономить на спичках. У вас запущенное приложение 300 КБ с лишним памяти занимает (при том что экзешник 2 КБ), а вы о 4 байтах беспокоитесь.

Comment: я просто курсовую пишу на тему радикальной оптимизации. Мне каждый байт важен. Но раз уж проще никак не сделать, то спасибо.

Comment: @rancid_rot под 64-битной архитектурой как правило нет смысла ужимать данный до 4-байтовых значений. Разве что если есть большой массив float, который нужно вывести через printf, тогда это может иметь смысл, и дополнительная 8-байтная переменная особой погоды не сделает. Плюс можно эту переменную сделать стековой.